# Cordova/PhoneGap UI responsiveness on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

We are deciding to use Cordova/PhoneGap engine for iOS application development. We looked at some samples in [PhoneGap app gallery](http://phonegap.com/app). Their responsiveness in the meaning of touch reaction time is very bad in comparison to native apps.

We also found some articles on improving the responsiveness. For example, [this one](http://www.mikedellanoce.com/2012/09/10-tips-for-getting-that-native-ios.html).

Now we want to see real world PhoneGap applications with the best possible UI responsiveness to be sure that it works. Do you know such applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the developer is using click events then you are going to get the 300ms delay before the event is fired. Instead they should be using tap events as the article you discovered mentions. There is really no way for us to know if a developer is doing things "the right way" unless we look at their code.

You should check out the Wikipedia app which was built using PG for example. As an added bonus all the source is available at:

https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile